# Keep data from cell and text on same printed line in word using vba

Tags: vba, ms-word, paste

I'm trying to make it say "Dear ______," but instead it gives me "Dear ____" and then the comma on the second line. Any help to get it on the same line would  be appreciated.

```
    .TypeText "Dear"
    Sheet1.Cells(10, 2).Copy
    wdapp.Selection.PasteAndFormat xlValue: .TypeText ","

    .TypeText vbNewLine
```

Comment: Can you replace it with`.TypeText "Dear " & Sheet1.Cells(10, 2).Value & "," & vbNewLine`, thus avoiding the copy/paste?

Comment: How do I get all of the formatting from the cell and not just the value though?

Answer (score 0):

Using strings works..

```
.typetext "Dear" & Sheet1.Cells(10,2).Value & "," & "    " vbcrlf
```

Thanks